# Why isn't this SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK “Hello World” application for SFDC Canvas working?

Tags: exception, canvas, salesforce, jetty, classpath

Currently I'm looking in the [Force.com Canvas Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/canvas_framework.pdf) at "Chapter 3: Quick Start--Advanced".

I've successfully cloned SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK from GitHub, and am now trying to Run the Web App Locally.

The build is successful and keystore has been created.  However, when I execute target\bin\webapp.bat, I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Main

Find that the main class seems to be in `C:\SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK\target\classes`, I modified the .bat file, to include this in the CLASSPATH:

```
set CLASSPATH="C:\SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK\target\classes;%BASEDIR%"\etc;"%REPO%"\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar;"%REPO%"\org\mortbay\jetty\jsp-2.1-glassfish\2.1.v20100127\jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar;"%REPO%"\org\eclipse\jdt\core\compiler\ecj\3.5.1\ecj-3.5.1.jar;"%REPO%"\org\mortbay\jetty\jsp-api-2.1-glassfish\2.1.v20100127\jsp-api-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20100127.jar;"%REPO%"\ant\ant\1.6.5\ant-1.6.5.jar;"%REPO%"\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.0\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.0.jar;"%REPO%"\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.0\jackson-core-asl-1.9.0.jar;"%REPO%"\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-webapp\7.6.0.v20120127\jetty-webapp-7.6.0.v20120127.jar;"%REPO%"\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-xml\7.6.0.v20120127\jetty-xml-7.6.0.v20120127.jar;"%REPO%"\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-util\7.6.0.v20120127\jetty-util-7.6.0.v20120127.jar;"%REPO%"\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-servlet\7.6.0.v20120127\jetty-servlet-7.6.0.v20120127.jar;"%REPO%"\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-security\7.6.0.v20120127\jetty-security-7.6.0.v20120127.jar;"%REPO%"\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-server\7.6.0.v20120127\jetty-server-7.6.0.v20120127.jar;"%REPO%"\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-continuation\7.6.0.v20120127\jetty-continuation-7.6.0.v20120127.jar;"%REPO%"\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-http\7.6.0.v20120127\jetty-http-7.6.0.v20120127.jar;"%REPO%"\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-io\7.6.0.v20120127\jetty-io-7.6.0.v20120127.jar;"%REPO%"\asm\asm\3.2\asm-3.2.jar;"%REPO%"\org\json\json\20080701\json-20080701.jar;"%REPO%"\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;"%REPO%"\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.0.4\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;"%REPO%"\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.4\commons-codec-1.4.jar;"%REPO%"\sfdc\sfdc-canvas-sdk\1.0-SNAPSHOT\sfdc-canvas-sdk-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This enables the batch file to execute and initiate Jetty.

However, when I attempt to visit `https://localhost:8443/examples/hello-world/index.jsp`, after getting past the browser warning message, I get an HTTP ERROR 500 page:

> > HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /examples/hello-world/index.jsp. Reason:
>
> ```
> PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP
> ```
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot
>   be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
>
> Caused by:
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Unable to compile class
>   for JSP
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot
>   be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
>
> at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:296)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:376)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:437)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:360)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:479)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:521)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:449)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:47)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:910)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:634)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:66)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:254)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.run(SslSocketConnector.java:665)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Powered by Jetty://

Concurrently, my Jetty server dies with:

> ERROR: Compilation error
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.(ClassFileReader.java:372)
>           at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTJavaCompiler$1.findType(JDTJavaCompiler.java:367)
>           at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTJavaCompiler$1.findType(JDTJavaCompiler.java:324)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:102)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1188)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromVariantTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java
>   :1244)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeArgumentsFromSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1
>   031)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1193)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethod(BinaryTypeBinding.java:495)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethods(BinaryTypeBinding.java:577)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.cachePartsFrom(BinaryTypeBinding.java:327)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:640)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:619)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.accept(Compiler.java:295)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:133)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:183)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.findImport(CompilationUnitScope.java:465)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.findSingleImport(CompilationUnitScope.java:519)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.faultInImports(CompilationUnitScope.java:368)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.faultInTypes(CompilationUnitScope.java:444)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:752)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:464)
>           at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTJavaCompiler.compile(JDTJavaCompiler.java:503)
>           at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:368)
>           at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:437)
>           at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:360)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:479)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:521)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:449)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:47)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:910)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:634)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:66)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:254)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.run(SslSocketConnector.java:665)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ERROR: Error compiling file:
>   C:\Users\Brian_Kessler@epam.com\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8443-webapp-_-any-\jsp\org\apa
>   che\jsp\examples\hello_002dworld\index_jsp.java 2014-12-11
>   15:35:48.106:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:/examples/hello-world/index.jsp
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Unable to compile class
>   for JSP||PWC6199: Generated servlet error:|The type java
>   .util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from
>   required .class files||
>           at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:123)
>           at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:296)
>           at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:376)
>           at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:437)
>           at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:360)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:479)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:521)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:449)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:47)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:910)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:634)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:66)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:254)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.run(SslSocketConnector.java:665)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

If it is relevant:

OS: Windows 7
Java: 1.8.0_25
Maven: 3.2.2

Any help to resolve this will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem @brian-kessler? I'm looking into a similar problem and currently suspect that the issue is incompatibility between Jetty v8 and Java 8, but if you discovered the cause it would be great to hear about it.

Comment: @MattSheppard, I don't recall ever finding either a solution nor a workaround.  Sorry.

Comment: No worries - Thanks for following up. I've looked a bit further and I'm fairly sure in my case an upgrade to Jetty 9 is required, but I haven't gotten JSP working in Jetty 9 either so far.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this as follows on MacOS Sierra 10.13.6

The problem does seem to be with Java 8, so if you can start the whole installation with Java 7, you'll save a lot of time. In my case, I had already installed Java 8, so I had to do the following:

1- Install java 7 from: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html . You have to create an Oracle account, it's free.

2- Confirm both versions of java are runningv

```
Pablos-MacBook-Pro:SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK pabloalvarez$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.8.0_191, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_80, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home
```

3- Then

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7.0_80`
export JAVACMD=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7.0_80`
```

Confirm that Java 7 is the default version now

```
Pablos-MacBook-Pro:SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK pabloalvarez$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

5- Then

```
export JAVACMD=/usr/bin/java
```

6- Finally

```
Pablos-MacBook-Pro:SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK pabloalvarez$ sh target/bin/webapp
Looks like we are NOT running on heroku.
2019-01-14 10:54:48.557:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.6.0.v20120127
2019-01-14 10:54:48.863:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/Users/pabloalvarez/SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK/src/main/webapp/}
2019-01-14 10:54:49.252:INFO:oejus.SslContextFactory:Enabled Protocols [SSLv2Hello, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2] of [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
```

Good luck!